# Laravel correct way to name and define routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

Example 1:

```
Route::get('/', 'API\PostController@index')->name(‘post.index’);
```

Example 2:

```
Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name(‘post.index’);
```

In this example we need to use the following use statement at the top of the route file:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\API\PostController;
```

The second example makes it easy to navigate across the controllers from the route file with a cmd + click but compared to better performance which is the best ?

Is it must to define named routes when using the laravel only as a API, can it add more overhead to overall performance ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a performance difference because you cache the routes in production with these commands: `php artisan optimize` or `php artisan route:cache`

Pick the one you prefer the most.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#route-caching

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter which one you choose to define your routes but it's recommended to use [route caching](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#route-caching) on production:

> If your application is exclusively using controller based routes, you
>   should take advantage of Laravel's route cache. Using the route cache
>   will drastically decrease the amount of time it takes to register all
>   of your application's routes. In some cases, your route registration
>   may even be up to 100x faster. To generate a route cache, just execute
>   the `route:cache` Artisan command:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Answer (score -1):

Route::get('/', 'API\PostController@index')->name('post.index');

try this hope it helps.